# What is IDetachedQuery and its difference with DetachedCriteria?

Tags: nhibernate, detachedcriteria

What is `IDetachedQuery` and its difference with `DetachedCriteria`? How and when `IDetachedQuery` is used?

UPDATE:

I'm using NHibernate 2.1.2.4000

Comment: In what assembly and with what version you've found this types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDetachedQuery is an interface implemented by DetachedQuery and DetachedNamedQuery.

DetachedQuery is like DetachedCriteria, but for HQL queries. DetachedNamedQuery is for named queries.

As far as I know you don't use the interface directly. Example of DetachedQuery:

```
var deleteQuery = new DetachedQuery("DELETE FROM myObject o WHERE o.Id = IN (:idList)")
                            .SetParameterList("idList", list);
deleteQuery.GetExecutableQuery(session).ExecuteUpdate();
```